# Continuous Function on a Set With Content Zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to prove a proposition about a continuous function over part of a compact set, and I have gotten stuck. The proof will be completed if I can verify the following:

If $f$ is a continuously partially differentiable function, $D$ is compact with Jordan content, and $C\subset D$ has Jordan content zero, is it true that $f(C)$ has Jordan content zero?

It would be true if $C$ was closed, since then $C$ would be compact with content zero, but can it also be shown true without the assumption that $C$ is closed?

Comment: If $D=[0,1]$ and $f\colon[0,1]\to[0,1]$ is the [Devil's staircase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) and $C$ is the standard Cantor set, then $f$ is continuous, $C$ is compact and has Jordan content $0$ (because $\partial C=C$ has Lebesgue measure zero), yet $f(C)=[0,1]$, which provides a counterexample but also contradicts your last paragraph. Maybe you forgot a hypothesis?

Comment: That's a good counterexample. It turns out I actually have a continuously partially differentiable function. I have updated the question. In this case, can it be shown?

Comment: Yes, I don't have enough time to write a full answer, but if $f$ is $k$-Lipschitz (which is implied by $C^1$), it will work, essentially because you can cover $C$ by not-too-many $\varepsilon$-balls, whose image under $f$ will be included in $k\varepsilon$-balls.

Answer (score 0):

As in my analysis book $C$ is only jordan measureable if its characteristic function is Rieman integrateable. Now assume $C$ is not necesserally closed.

The $\epsilon$ hull is defined this way: $U_\epsilon(C)=\{x\in D, \exists y\in C: |x-y| < \epsilon\}$

Therefore $|U_\epsilon|$ of $C$ must converge to 0 when epsilon converges to 0, otherwise it wouldnt be R-integrateable, because you could define a series of mesh such that a subset of the mesh contains always contains elements of C, but has not content 0.

Because $f´$ is defined on a compact set, it must be bounded and therefore $f$ is lipschitz continuous with constant L, which leads to:

$|f(U_\epsilon(C))| \leq L*|U_\epsilon(C)|$

Note that $U_\epsilon(C)$ is an open set and can be expressed as finite union of spheres of radius $\epsilon$, this should follow from properties of covering compactness.
It can be easily prooved, that the inequality holds for a single sphere, summing up yields the above.

If you take $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}$ you get your result.

Comment: @hardmath Sorry that was a really heartless answer in the first place, should be fixed now.